# Save object or array in collection variables to have range of numbers to compare in test

Tags: variables, postman

Currently, I encountered a small problem.
I have a goal: to test counter(functionality that calculates numbers) in order to check this counter returns a number that falls under **set range** of low and high (+-5% deviation)

Now, I have this piece of code:

```
var allLists = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var min = pm.variables.get("count"); // I separately extract min
var max = pm.variables.get("count1"); // and max, but want to extract one variable with min and max;
var low = parseInt(min)
var high = parseInt(max);
console.log("::MIN_VALIE: " + low + " | " + "::MAX_VALUE: " + high);

pm.test("test count", function () {
    const value = allLists.data.count;
    console.log(":::::::::=> COUNTER: " + value);
    pm.expect(typeof value).to.eql('number');
    pm.expect(value > low && value < high).to.eql(true);
});
```

It works ok, but I believe this code is bulky
In order to compare that **value** in the range of low and high I have to keep low and high number in collection variable, that out of desired 50 variables makes 100 variables and real mess.

Can I somehow keep one variable for **low** and **high** value in collection variables?

**UPDATE:**
Right after posting came up with it:

```
var allLists = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var num = pm.variables.get("count").split(',');
var min = parseInt(num[0]);
var max = parseInt(num[1]);

console.log("::MIN_VALIE: " + min + " | " + "::MAX_VALUE: " + max);

pm.test("test count", function () {
    const value = allLists.data.count;
    console.log(":::::::::=> COUNTER: " + value);
    pm.expect(typeof value).to.eql('number');
    pm.expect(15 > min && 15 < max).to.eql(true);
});
```

it's much better, but maybe exists better way

Comment: Could you add more details about the response data please? What are the variables that you have set? Are these created somewhere else or manually created?

Comment: I manually set a variable on collection variables level. It's not generated from somewhere, it's just assigned.

Comment: And the response data? Just trying to understand the problem more and suggest an alternative solution. What is the value of `allLists`?

Comment: in AllLists return number I want to compare to be in range of min and max (min and max I written down in collection variables). I resolved this problem with const num = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get("overall_count")); and now that's what I wanted to have. Anyway thanks for the response!

Comment: That fine, somethings you just need to externalise the problem and find a solution on your own. I would suggest adding more implemention details to the question in the future - take a step back after writing it and think about what information is missing that could be added.

Comment: Yeah, I will take it into account. But I guess I really written a lot information

Comment: By the way. @DannyDainton did you need to use json data file in newman for newman test. I made good, but the ideal option will be to use separate json file to keep variables there. Didn't you try?

Comment: Not sure I follow - it was difficult to try anything, given the information you provided. You provided a one sided  Postman view of the problem and they were too many gaps to piece it together. Didn't know what the response data was so I couldn't check anything locally.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it with JSON.parse. In collection variable the range is written down as In Collection Varibles:
overall_count:[1,99] format, that I wanted to have.

```
var allLists = JSON.parse(responseBody);
// Here I parse this variable and make parse int to get integer and hurray, I have 1 variable instead of 2
const num = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get("overall_count")); //resolved it with JSON parsing
var min = parseInt(num[0]);
var max = parseInt(num[1]);

pm.test("test count", function () {
    const value = allLists.data.count;
    pm.expect(typeof value).to.eql('number');
    pm.expect(15 > min && 15 < max).to.eql(true);
});
```